# Whats the best way to join many vectors into a new vector?

Tags: vector, rust

To create a new vector with the contents of other vectors, I'm currently doing this:

```
fn func(a: &Vec<i32>, b: &Vec<i32>, c: &Vec<i32>) {
    let abc = Vec<i32> = {
        let mut tmp = Vec::with_capacity(a.len(), b.len(), c.len());
        tmp.extend(a);
        tmp.extend(b);
        tmp.extend(c);
        tmp
    };

    // ...
}
```

Is there a more straightforward / elegant way to do this?

Comment: A small, unrelated note: passing `&Vec<i32>` is almost never necessary in rust. Instead, the convention is to pass the slice directly `&[i32]` which is more flexible as `Vec<T>` `Deref`s to `[T]`. `Vec` is designed as a dynamically growable slice, and seeing as they are being borrowed immutably here, we might as well just take the slices directly. Anyway, I realise this is probably pseudo-ish code, just thought I'd mention it for passersby.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a `concat` method that can be used for this, however the values need to be slices, or borrowable to slices, not `&Vec<_>` as given in the question.

An example, similar to the question:

```
fn func(a: &Vec<i32>, b: &Vec<i32>, c: &Vec<i32>) {
    let abc = Vec<i32> = [a.as_slice(), b.as_slice(), c.as_slice()].concat();

    // ...
}
```

However, as @mindTree notes, using `&[i32]` type arguments is more idiomatic and removes the need for conversion. eg:

```
fn func(a: &[i32], b: &[i32], c: &[i32]) {
    let abc = Vec<i32> = [a, b, c].concat();

    // ...
}
```

[`SliceConcatExt::concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html#tymethod.concat) is a more general version of your function and can join multiple slices to a Vec. It will sum the sizes each slice to pre-allocate a Vec of the right capacity, then extend repeatedly.

```
fn concat(&self) -> Vec<T> {
    let size = self.iter().fold(0, |acc, v| acc + v.borrow().len());
    let mut result = Vec::with_capacity(size);
    for v in self {
        result.extend_from_slice(v.borrow())
    }
    result
}
```

Comment: How should this be accessed? using the `concat!` macro? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat!.html

Comment: @ideasman42 - `SliceConcatExt<T>` is implemented for `[V] where V: Borrow<[T]>`, which means we can concat a `Vec<Vec<i32>>` (`vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4]].concat() == vec![1, 2, 3, 4]`), or a fixed-size array (`[[1, 2], [3, 4]].concat()`) and other combinations.

Comment: I can't get this working, `[a, b, c].concat()` gives error ``no method named `concat` found``, `concat!(a, b, c)` raises error `expected a literal`.

Comment: @ideasman42 - [This playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e85dc7b145b564e4f12df07568ef3fb9&version=stable&backtrace=0) replaces the body of your function with `.concat()`. As @mindTree mentioned, `&Vec<i32>` is an odd thing to pass, and not really idiomatic, so I replaced them with slices.

Comment: Other than just inlining the function body?

Comment: Yes, since this is a fairly primitive operation, having to create functions whenever its done seems strange. Since asking this question, I found out how, your answer that used a function relied on coercion, which is OK but makes the answer confusing for a newcomer.

Comment: @ideasman42: the `concat!` macro is there to catenate literal `&'static str` at compile-time, it's a completely different beast :)

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution might be to use the `Chain` iterator:

```
let abc: Vec<_> = a.iter().chain(b).chain(c).collect();
```

However, in your example you are borrowing the slices, so we'll need to either deref each borrowed element or use the `Cloned` iterator to copy each integer. `Cloned` is probably a bit easier and as efficient as we are working with small `Copy` data (`i32`):

```
let abc: Vec<_> = a.iter().cloned()
    .chain(b.iter().cloned())
    .chain(c.iter().cloned())
    .collect();
```

Seeing as each of these iterators are `ExactSizeIterator`s, it should be possible to allocate the exact size for the target `Vec` up front, however I'm unware whether or not this is *actually* the case in the std implementation (they might be waiting on specialization to land before adding this optimisation).